# ¿ como podría hacer para validar si existe el correo antes de hacer un registro, todo esto usando promesas?

Tags: nodejs, angular, promesas, registro

estoy siguiendo un tutorial para hacer un registro y un login con angular y node.js. En dicho tutorial no hacen la validación, simplemente registran el usuario y listo. El código para hacer el insert es este:

```js
const insert = ({user,name, lastName, pass, email}) => {
 return new Promise( (resolve,reject) => {
  bd.query('INSERT INTO usuario (usuario,nombres,apellidos,clave,correo)  VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)', ['JULIAN',name,lastName,pass,email], (err,rows)=>{
   return (err)? reject(err): resolve(rows);
  }); 
 });
};
```

Yo hice esta función para validar si el usuario ya está registrado en la base de datos:

```js
const getByEmail = (email) => {
 return new Promise( (resolve,reject) => {
  bd.query('SELECT * from usuario WHERE correo = ?', [email], (err, rows) => {
   return (err) ? reject(err): resolve(rows);
  });
 });
};
```

y está función es donde pienso unir las 2 funciones anteriores, para poder validar si el usuario ya existe, si existe mandar un error o un mensaje al front, y si no existe hacer el insert en la Base de datos.

```js
const registerUser = ( {user,name, lastName, pass, email} ) => {
getByEmail(email)
 .then( ( {user,name, lastName, pass, email} ) => {
  //aquí iría un condicional para saber si la respuesta de la promesa anterior trajo un resultado (existe el usuario) o no.

  insert({user,name, lastName, pass, email});
 })
 .catch( errors => {
  res.send(errors);
 })
};
```

El problema es que me está mostrando este error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si hago un console.log de name, por ejemplo, me dice: undefined. mi idea era que la función getByEmail me devolviera si el correo existe o no en la base de datos, y entonces, si existe, llamar al insert con los datos {user,name,lastname,pass,email} para poder hacer el registro, pero creo que dentro del .then no puedo acceder a esos parametros, o no se por que me dice undefined, no se si es que es que estoy planteando mal la solución, pero no hallo la solución

Gracias de antemano al que me pueda ayudar. Saludos!

Comment: Syntax error es un error de compilación: `.then( ({user,name, lastName, pass, email}) {`. Ahí falta una flecha `=>` para indicar que estás definiendo una función

Comment: Cierto, era ese el problema de ese error, aunque lo resolví y me aparece otro, acabo de editar mi pregunta (con el error resuelto) para aclarar todo, y agregué cuál es mi idea, o lo que quiero lograr exactamente, creo que mi solución o como lo estoy planteando no es la correcta.

Comment: No sería más simple definir esa columna como unique?

Comment: cuando resuelves `getByEmail` resuelves un array por lo tanto en el `then` no te llega un objeto como parametro sino un array con las filas. Creo que hay puede estar el error

Comment: @BetaM , esa sería una solución para evitar hacer validaciones siempre ? no había pensado resolverlo de esa forma.

Comment: Esa regla de validación siempre la disparara el motor de bases de datos ya solo te queda a ti embellecer la para mostrar el aviso al usuario

Comment: O la otra es almacenar en una variable un Select count de esa tabla, si devuelve cero entonces el registro no existe y si es mayor a cero entonces el registro ya existe y actúas en concecuencia impidiendo el registro

Comment: @BetaM lo hice con un Selec * from, y luego verifico si la consulta me retorna una fila es por que el correo ya existe. pero lo más correcto sería hacerlo con el UNIQUE en la base de datos ? soy novato, y la verdad no se cuál opción sería la mejor, o la más eficiente.

Comment: No hay solución única, la que apliques esa está bien